# Problema para atualizar dados

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Bom dia amigos, estou a mais ou menos a uns 3 dias com dificuldades em um erro que vem ocorrendo em minha aplicação.

Tenho duas entidades, CLIENTE e VEI. Fiz o mapeamento de forma bidirecional dizendo que meu cliente pode ter um ou mais veiculos.

```
private List<Veiculo> veiculo = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente", cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public List<Veiculo> getVeiculo() {
    return veiculo;}
```

Consigo fazer o cadastro do Cliente e do veiculo relacionado a ele normalmente. Porem nao consigo edita-los(atuzalizar). Criei uma tela onde pesquiso o cliente.
[image: Tela de pesquisa de cliente]
Quando clico no botao editar, ele pega o valor do id faz a conversao e jogo os dados ja preenchidos para a tela de edição de cliente. Todos os valores sao preenchidos como deveriam normalmente, porem ao tentar salvar o objeto cliente depois de feita alguma alteração. tenho o seguinte erro.

```
out 31, 2018 11:44:58 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
ADVERTÊNCIA: #{cadastroClienteBean.salvar}: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Cliente.veiculo, could not initialize proxy - no Session
javax.faces.FacesException: #{cadastroClienteBean.salvar}: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Cliente.veiculo, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Cliente.veiculo, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: model.Cliente.veiculo, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.write(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.add(PersistentBag.java:291)
    at Controller.CadastroClienteBean.cadastrarCarro(CadastroClienteBean.java:38)
    at Controller.CadastroClienteBean.salvar(CadastroClienteBean.java:42)
    at Controller.CadastroClienteBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.salvar(CadastroClienteBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more
```

Porem eu quero atualizar apenas os dados do cliente e nao do veiculos relacionado a ele neste momento, como resolver isso?

Ainda estou iniciando, qualquer coisa pode pedir que eu respondo
att;

Erro ao utilizar a formatacão EAGER

```
ADVERTÊNCIA: #{cadastroClienteBean.salvar}: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
javax.faces.FacesException: #{cadastroClienteBean.salvar}: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:92)
    at util.jpa.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleMethodInvocation.java:30)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:112)
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:55)
    at service.CadastroClienteService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.salvar(CadastroClienteService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.java)
    at Controller.CadastroClienteBean.salvar(CadastroClienteBean.java:43)
    at Controller.CadastroClienteBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.salvar(CadastroClienteBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [model.Veiculo] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='não pode ser nulo', propertyPath=placa, rootBeanClass=class model.Veiculo, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1234)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
    ... 53 more
```

**Metodo Salvar da minha classe service**

```
@Inject
    private Clientes clientes;

    @Transactional
    public Cliente salvar(Cliente cliente) {

        Cliente clienteExisente = clientes.porNome(cliente.getNome());

        if (clienteExisente != null && clienteExisente.equals(cliente)) {
            throw new NegocioException("Ja existe um cliente com esse mesmo nome!");
        }

        return clientes.guardar(cliente);
    }
```

**Repository**

```
@Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public Cliente guardar(Cliente cliente) {
        return manager.merge(cliente);
    }
```

Comment: o jeito mais rápido de resolver seu problema seria trocar seu fetchtype para eager, mas dependendo da quantidade de dados que você pretende ter na sua lista isso poderá ficar pesado, existem formas mais especificas mas para cita-las seria interessante entender mais o seu código e a sua situação, aqui tem umas informações legais: http://blog.caelum.com.br/enfrentando-a-lazyinitializationexception-no-hibernate/

Comment: Rodrigo, acrescente no seu post seu método de salvar. Mudar o `fetch` para `EAGER` provavelmente resolveria seu problema, mas a princípio não é uma solução boa. A propósito essa anotação de `LAZY` nem é necessária porque, por padrão, listas são `lazy`.

Comment: Opa, Obrigado amigos, eu tentei fazer da forma como os senhores me explicaram. Porem ao alterar de fetch para EAGER o erro informado é outro. Vou atualizar o topico com o erro em EAGER. E colocar o metodo de salvar

Comment: Agora o problema mudou completamente de contexto: `interpolatedMessage='não pode ser nulo', propertyPath=placa`. Pelo que parece, você está tentando salvar um objeto inválido.

Comment: Exato, ele pede para que eu informe o valor do Veiculo relacionado ao cliente que eu estou tentando atualizar.  Porem como fazer isso se nao quero atualizar nada relacionado ao veiculo dele, e sim somente os dados do cliente. ? Me desculpem eu estou iniciando e ainda nao descobri como resolver.

Comment: Ele nem chega a verificar essa variavel, nao sei se é relevante, mais na minha tela de cadastro de cliente, eu estou adicinando o meu veiculo ao cliente de forma manual após os valores serem preenchidos.  inicio instanciando um new veiculo, e um new cliente, e com os dados ja preenchidos, eu faço assim, public void cadastrarCarro() {
  this.veiculo.setCliente(cliente);
  this.cliente.getVeiculo().add(this.veiculo);
 } e depois public void salvar() {
  cadastrarCarro();
  this.cadastroClienteService.salvar(this.cliente);

  FacesUtil.addInforMessage("Cadastro Salvo com sucesso!");
 }

Comment: Acredito que tenha identificado qual é meu problema, irei tentar executar as correcões e aviso os senhores, obrigado pela ajuda. Desculpe minha falta de conhecimento em talvez lhes fornecer poucas informacoes, ou informacoes destorcidas. Volto com noticias